# Create 2D views from a cad file

Tags: opengl

I need to create images of 2d perspective views of 3d models.
I was thinking of using **opengl** or **vtk** but I don't know how to achieve this with either of them.

Notes:

- I need to create multiple views and taking screenshots is not feasible. I want to change the "camera matrix" in order to create views and output images.
- The Os I'm working with is Linux.

Comment: 1. Do you have the required CAD software or do you need a solution that does not require CAD software? 2. Do you have 100s of files to make views of where this should be an automated process? 3. Can you just open the CAD software and take a screenshot of each 2d view you want? 4. Which OS do you need this for? Be specific.

Comment: hi, sorry i haven't been specific.

Comment: i need to create multiple views and taking screenshot is not feasible. i want to change the "camera matrix" in order to create views and output images

Comment: the Os i'm working with is Linux

Answer (score 0):

One of the many options you have would be to use [Onshape](https://www.onshape.com/), a free web-based CAD program. It supports import of various 3D models, including STL files.

A feature in Onshape is the ability to create orthographic drawings from the original model. You have the ability to create the drawing with "standard" front, right and top views as well as the isometric rendering, or you can customize the views you wish to include.

The drawing below began as an STL file, created in a flash with [Tinkercad](https://www.tinkercad.com/) (not my choice) and imported to Onshape.

[image: onshape drawing]

Comment: Onshape is free only under certain circumstances. For one, your data if fully exposed so the free version is essentially useless for commercial applications where confidentiality is necessary.

Comment: Yes, for sensitive documents, one would want to import the model, create and download the drawing, then delete the files.

Comment: If this were to be for a patent illustration, I’d avoid even a transient upload as it could conceivably be considered publication.